Dealing with unwanted chrome cache data & visual studio log file
I am not sure this is the best way to deal with these unwanted files.
YES I wrote a small VB.Net application to delete chrome cache data files that have this format "f_00006a" & another file that shows up in a Temp folder every time I start my computer "dd_updateconfiuration_202.log" and
if my computer is idle for 10 min or more Visual Studio tries to update
and adds a bunch of these dd files to the temp folder REAL Annoying
YES I have VS 2019 and have it set to not request updates
Here is the code I wrote to deal with this feel free to offer suggestions
for improvements to this code. It works fine but seems like overkill to
deal with the situation.
Public Class frmStart
Public Sub frmStart_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 27 Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnVCache_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVCache.Click

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\Dwight\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\Cache_Data\"
    Process.Start(folderPath)
    'Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized

End Sub

Private Sub btnVTemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVTemp.Click

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\Dwight\AppData\Local\Temp\"
    Process.Start(folderPath)

End Sub

Private Sub btnDelCache_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelCache.Click

    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\Dwight\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\Cache_Data\"
    Dim filePattern As String = "f*"
    Dim result As MsgBoxResult = Nothing
    Dim files As IEnumerable(Of String) = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, filePattern)

    lstFiles.Items.Clear() 'WORKS where to use it and HOW TO USE
    Try

        If files.Any() Then

            MsgBox("Files Found", vbOKOnly, "File Deletion")

            result = MsgBox("Yes to Delete Files" & vbCrLf & "NO ONLY View Files", vbYesNo, "File Deletion")

            If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

                For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)
                    Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(fileName)
                    Dim fC As String = fileName.Replace(folderPath, String.Empty)

                    If fC.Substring(0, 1) = "f" Then
                        lstFiles.Items.Add(fileName.Replace(folderPath, String.Empty))
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(fileName, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin, FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)
                    End If

                Next

                MsgBox("Files Deleted", vbOKOnly, "File Deletion")

            ElseIf result = MsgBoxResult.No Then

                Dim file As String = folderPath.Replace(folderPath, String.Empty)
                For Each file In files
                    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(file)
                    lstFiles.Items.Add(fileName)
                Next

            End If
            'Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox("NO Files With" & "   f   " & "FOUND", vbOKOnly, "File Deletion")

        End If
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        MessageBox.Show("Access to the folder is denied.")
    Catch ex As DirectoryNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("The specified folder does not exist.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelTemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelTemp.Click

    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\Dwight\AppData\Local\Temp\"
    Dim result As MsgBoxResult = Nothing
    ' Get all files in the folder that start with "dd"
    Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "dd*")

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    ' Check if any files are found
    If files.Length = 0 Then
        result = MsgBox("No Files to Delete", vbOKOnly, "File Deletion")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    result = MsgBox("Yes to Delete Files" & vbCrLf & "NO to EXIT", vbYesNo, "File Deletion")
    If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        For Each file As String In files
            lstFiles.Items.Add(file.Replace(folderPath, String.Empty))
            ' Send file to recycle bin
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(file, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin, FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)

        Next

        MsgBox("Files Deleted", vbOKOnly, "File Deletion")
    ElseIf result = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        MsgBox("NO Files DELETED", vbOKOnly, "File Deletion")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnOpenRB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenRB.Click

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    Dim userSid As String = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value

    ' Construct the path to the Recycle Bin for the current user
    Dim recycleBinPath As String = String.Format("C:\$Recycle.Bin\{0}", userSid)

    ' Start a new process to open Windows Explorer at the Recycle Bin path
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", recycleBinPath)

End Sub

End Class


A new auxiliary method, IsListBoxInitialized, is added to check whether the ListBox control has been initialized. Avoid checking whether lstFiles is empty every time when calling other methods.

In the btnVCache_Click and btnVTemp_Click methods, clear the contents of the ListBox and try to open the specified cache folder path using explorer.exe.

In btnDelCache_Click and btnDelTemp_Click methods, asynchronous processing (Async) is introduced to improve the user experience. Use Task.Run to delete files in the background thread.

A new button click event btnOpenRB_Click is added to open the recycle bin. This is achieved by starting explorer.exe and passing in the special path shell:: {645ff040-5081-11b-9F08-00aa002f954e}.

Error handling logic has been added in many places, such as the case that the file does not exist and access is denied, which improves the robustness and user-friendliness of the program.



Public Class Form1
Private Const CacheFolderPath As String = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\Cache_Data"
Private Const TempFolderPath As String = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\"

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Function IsListBoxInitialized() As Boolean
    If lstFiles Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("ListBox control 'lstFiles' is not initialized.")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub frmStart_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 27 Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnVCache_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVCache.Click
    If Not IsListBoxInitialized() Then Return

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    If Not Directory.Exists(CacheFolderPath) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cache folder path does not exist.")
        Return
    End If

    Try
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", CacheFolderPath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could not open folder: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnVTemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVTemp.Click
    If Not IsListBoxInitialized() Then Return

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    If Not Directory.Exists(TempFolderPath) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Temp folder path does not exist.")
        Return
    End If

    Try
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", TempFolderPath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could not open folder: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Async Sub btnDelCache_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelCache.Click
    If Not IsListBoxInitialized() Then Return

    Dim files As IEnumerable(Of String) = Directory.EnumerateFiles(CacheFolderPath, "f*")

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    Try
        If files.Any() Then
            Dim fileCount As Integer = files.Count()
            Dim result = MessageBox.Show($"Found {fileCount} files. Proceed with deletion?", "File Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

            If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                For Each fileName In files
                    Dim fC As String = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
                    lstFiles.Items.Add(fC)
                    Await Task.Run(Sub() System.IO.File.Delete(fileName))
                Next
                MessageBox.Show("Files Deleted", "File Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Else
                For Each file In files
                    lstFiles.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file))
                Next
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No files with 'f' found", "File Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End If
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        MessageBox.Show("Access to the folder is denied.")
    Catch ex As DirectoryNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("The specified folder does not exist.")
    Catch ex As IOException
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Async Sub btnDelTemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelTemp.Click
    If Not IsListBoxInitialized() Then Return

    Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(TempFolderPath, "dd*")

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()

    If files.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No files to delete", "File Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Return
    End If

    Dim result = MessageBox.Show($"Found {files.Length} files. Proceed with deletion?", "File Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Try
            For Each file In files
                lstFiles.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file))
                Await Task.Run(Sub() System.IO.File.Delete(file))
            Next
            MessageBox.Show("Files Deleted", "File Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            MessageBox.Show("Access to the folder is denied.")
        Catch ex As DirectoryNotFoundException
            MessageBox.Show("The specified folder does not exist.")
        Catch ex As IOException
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No files deleted", "File Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnOpenRB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenRB.Click
    If Not IsListBoxInitialized() Then Return

    lstFiles.Items.Clear()
    Try
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", "shell:::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could not open Recycle Bin: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class


Thanks for the code review I should have pointed out both folder paths always exist and contain some files and folders I did not want to delete or was not sure I should delete I write my own msgbox but did not include it in the post my bad still I appreciate you adding them in your code Busy woodworking will test your code It looks great Welcome to SO THANKS for the reply and taking the time

not sure why Async did a search makes sense but how BIG is any thread in this little App Private Async Sub btnDelCache_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelCache.Click
Async: This keyword indicates that the method is asynchronous. An Async method allows you to use the Await keyword inside it to run asynchronous operations without blocking the main thread. I seldom have thread management concerns but your code demonstrates a lot of advanced code design thanks for the lesson

